# opengl fragment shader storing color in 16 bytes

Tags: python, opengl, pyopengl

I use the following standard fragment shader:

```
#version 330
in vec4 v_color;
out vec4 FragColor;
void main()
{
   FragColor = v_color;
}
```

With the following standard vertex shader

```
#version 330
uniform mat4   u_view;          // View matrix
uniform mat4   u_projection;    // Projection matrix
in vec4 a_color;
in vec3 a_position;
out vec4 v_color;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = u_projection * u_view * vec4(a_position, 1.0);
    v_color = a_color;
}
```

My problem is that I use 16 bytes to represent the color, this creates some memory waste in CPU while generating the vertices.

Can I reduce the size of the color to 4 bytes?

Comment: Um... what's stopping you from doing that? Also, what do your shader have to do with any of this? This is basic vertex formatting stuff, which has little to do with shaders.

Comment: mmm As I understand this, since I define it as vec4, it is 4 bytes per value

Comment: @user972014 `vec4` is a datatype. It is a tuple with 4 floating point components. The shader doesn't specify the internal format of the array of vertex attributes or the framebuffer.